# Trying to set text of a textField with no luck

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm trying to read data from a database and set it as text in a textfield when I click a button. I can't for the life of me figure out why this code doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Label works, and textfield doesn't. They're in the same anchor pane.

Here's the code from my FXMLcontroller.java file. I used SceneBuilder to create the UI.

```
package winfin_test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Sam
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    private TextField textField1 = new TextField();


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonData(ActionEvent event) {

            try {
            //Connect to the database
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database";
            String uName = "root";
            String uPass = "data";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

            //Execute some SQL and load the records into the resultset
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String SQL = "Select * FROM data_test";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            //Move the cursor to the first record and get data
            rs.next();
            int id_col = rs.getInt("Auto_ID");
            String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
            String first = rs.getString("FirstName");
            String last = rs.getString("LastName");
            String dob = rs.getString("Birthday");
            String phone = rs.getString("Phone");

            //Display the first record in the text fields
              label.setText(first);
              textField1.setText(last);
        }
        catch (SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        //label.setText("Well Done!");
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

}
```

Comment: FYI, I can put a second label in instead of a textfield to receive the last name variable, and I get the same result - nothing! Why can I get one variable to pass to label, but not a second one to pass to either label or textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never add the textField to your scene, you have the `@FXML` label for your Label, but then the textField you are trying to create dynamically, but never displaying. Instead, define the textfield in your .fxml document, and then edit your code to the following:

```
package winfin_test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Sam
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private TextField textField1;


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonData(ActionEvent event) {

            try {
            //Connect to the database
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database";
            String uName = "root";
            String uPass = "data";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

            //Execute some SQL and load the records into the resultset
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String SQL = "Select * FROM data_test";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            //Move the cursor to the first record and get data
            rs.next();
            int id_col = rs.getInt("Auto_ID");
            String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
            String first = rs.getString("FirstName");
            String last = rs.getString("LastName");
            String dob = rs.getString("Birthday");
            String phone = rs.getString("Phone");

            //Display the first record in the text fields
              label.setText(first);
              textField1.setText(last);
        }
        catch (SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        //label.setText("Well Done!");
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

}
```

I know it seems silly that you need to write `@FXML` before every single variable declaration that you are linking to an fx:id, but that's just the way it is. If you have multiple variables of the same type, (eg: a group of Labels) you only need to put it once and separate then with commas, like so:

```
@FXML
Label label1, label2, label3, label4;
```

Which saves you a bit of code.

Comment: That was the trick. I knew it would be something easy that a newbie forgot. My rule of thumb is to beat my head against a wall for about 2 hours, scour this site and the internet for solutions, then come and ask. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! It's a little bit of a strange notation until you get used to it :) Good luck!